# limit forked samtools processes with gnu parallel within for and while loop including awk

Tags: bash, loops, fork, gnu-parallel, samtools

I'm trying to limit a parallelized script. Aim of the script is to get a list within 10 samples/folders, and use the records of the list to perform a samtools command, which is the most demanding part.

this is the simple version:

```
for (10 items)
do
  while read (list 5000 items)
  do
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
    ...
    samtools view -L input1 input2 |many_pipes_including_'awk' > output_file &
    ### TODO (WARNING): currently all processes are forked at the same time. this needs to be resolved. limit to a certain number of processes.
  done
done
```

To make use of our local server, the script contains a forking command, which works. But it will fork until all of the server's resources are used and no one else can work on it.

Therefore I wanted to implement something like `parallel -j 50` with gnu parallel. I tried it in front of the to-be-forked `samtools`command such as

```
parallel -j 50 -k samtools view -L input1 input2 |many_pipes_including_'awk' > output_file &
```

which did not work (also tried with backticks), I got either

```
[main_samview] region "item_from_list" specifies an unknown reference name. Continue anyway.
```

or somehow even `vim` was invoked. But I'm also not sure whether this is the right position for the `parallel`command within the script. Do you have any idea how to resolve this, so that the number of processes forked are limited?

I also thought of implementing something mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop/103921 with the FIFO-based semaphore, but I hoped `gnu parallel` can do what I'm looking for? I checked more pages such as https://zvfak.blogspot.de/2012/02/samtools-in-parallel.html and https://davetang.org/muse/2013/11/18/using-gnu-parallel/ but it is usually not this combination of issues.

This is a more detailed version of the script, in case any commands in there might be relevant (I heard the awk backticks and new lines in general might be a problem?)

```
cd path_to_data
for SAMPLE_FOLDER in *
do
cd ${SAMPLE_FOLDER}/another_folder
    echo "$SAMPLE_FOLDER was found"

    cat list_with_products.txt | while read PRODUCT_NAME_NO_SPACES 
    do
    PRODUCT_NAME=`echo ${PRODUCT_NAME_NO_SPACES} | tr "@" " "`
        echo "$PRODUCT_NAME with white spaces"
        BED_FILENAME=${BED_DIR}/intersect_${PRODUCT_NAME_NO_SPACES}_${SAMPLE_FOLDER}.bed
        grep "$PRODUCT_NAME" file_to_search_through > ${TMP_DIR}/tmp.gff

        cat ${TMP_DIR}/tmp.gff | some 'awk' command  > ${BED_FILENAME}

        samtools view -L ${BED_FILENAME} another_input_file.bam | many | pipes | with | 'awk' | and | perl | etc > resultfolder/resultfile &
          ### TODO (WARNING): currently all processes are forked at the same time. this needs to be resolved. limit to a certain number of processes.
        rm ${TMP_DIR}/tmp.gff
    done
    cd (back_to_start)
done
rmdir -p ${OUTPUT_DIR}/tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making a function that takes a single sample+single product as input:

```
cd path_to_data
# Process a single sample and a single product name
doit() {
    SAMPLE_FOLDER="$1"
    PRODUCT_NAME_NO_SPACES="$2"
    SEQ="$3"
    # Make sure temporary files are named uniquely
    # so any parallel job will not overwrite these.
    GFF=${TMP_DIR}/tmp.gff-$SEQ
    cd ${SAMPLE_FOLDER}/another_folder
    echo "$SAMPLE_FOLDER was found"

    PRODUCT_NAME=`echo ${PRODUCT_NAME_NO_SPACES} | tr "@" " "`
        echo "$PRODUCT_NAME with white spaces"
        BED_FILENAME=${BED_DIR}/intersect_${PRODUCT_NAME_NO_SPACES}_${SAMPLE_FOLDER}.bed
        grep "$PRODUCT_NAME" file_to_search_through > $GFF

        cat $GFF | some 'awk' command  > ${BED_FILENAME}

        samtools view -L ${BED_FILENAME} another_input_file.bam | many | pipes | with | 'awk' | and | perl | etc
        rm $GFF
    rmdir -p ${OUTPUT_DIR}/tmp
}
export -f doit
# These variables are defined outside the function and must be exported to be visible
export BED_DIR
export TMP_DIR
export OUTPUT_DIR
# If there are many of these variables, use env_parallel instead of
# parallel. Then you do not need to export the variables.
```

If `list_with_products.txt` is the same for every sample:

```
parallel --results outputdir/ doit {1} {2} {#} ::: * :::: path/to/list_with_products.txt
```

If `list_with_products.txt` is different for each sample:

```
# Generate a list of:
# sample \t product
parallel --tag cd {}\;cat list_with_products.txt ::: * |
  # call doit on each sample,product. Put output in outputdir
  parallel --results outputdir/ --colsep '\t' doit {1} {2} {#}
```

Comment: that looks awesome...and it feels kind of ok right now that I couldn't come up with a solution by myself. It's the first thing I'm gonna try tomorrow morning...but one question: there is no process-limiting parameter included atm right? So instead of `parallel doit` I would use `parallel -j 50 doit` ?

Comment: Ahh, yes. GNU Parallel defaults to the number of cpu cores, but you can force 50 with -j50.

Comment: I first tried to run my whole script including the loops with `parallel`. so I used `parallel -j 30 -n0 bash my_script.sh :::: 1` to run one instance of the script with the input and output hardcoded within the script...but regardless of `-j` it only used one core and only ran for one item in the loop. If I have more instances running, each of them processes the same item. I guess that is why you made a function out of it? How would I include the information from the "sample folder" loop here? BTW: it is the same `list_with_products` for the 10 samples

Comment: The way you use GNU Parallel is wrong. You need to learn the basics. May I suggest you walk through the tutorial? `man parallel_tutorial` If you still are not clear on how to use it, then look at the examples half way through `man parallel`.

Comment: The `parallel manual` is on my screen all the time ;-) I think I get more of the idea and can also better understand what you suggested above, testing it at the moment.

Comment: it works! took me some time to understand the input format and so on, but now it runs! Thanks for your help (and for writing this tool in the first place)!